# Python: How to check key existence in a nested structure?

Tags: python

I would like to improve the below snippet.

Problems are:

1. The key i am searching for is at different levels of my object or
   might not exist at all.
2. I do different things with the value tied to
   that key.

Thanks for the help!

```
conditions = {}
try:
   conditions["description"]=request.json()["weather"][0]["description"]
except KeyError:
   pass

try:
   conditions["temperature"]=round(request.json()["main"]["temp"], 1)
except KeyError:
   pass

...

return conditions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict.get()` with a default value

So

```
conditions["description"]=request.json().get("weather", [dict()])[0].get("description", "nodescription")
```

In this example if the key weather (which I presume contains a list) doesn't exist 
the default value will be a list with an empty dict, and this will prevent any KeyError or IndexError. Then the default value for items with no key `description` will be a value that you specify, in this case "nodescription". Hope it makes sense.